# How to customize `Edit-Post` Screen

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, templates

I have found `edit-form-advance.php` in /admin/ that contain layout of edit-post page

Have any way to customize layout via `add_action();` ? because I didn't want to edit directly within Wordpress admin file.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to add metaboxes, remove existing metaboxes, or move metaboxes between columns? ( they're drag and drop )

Comment: No, just change "layout" like a custom table view for editing mode.

Comment: The layout of the edit page or the layout of the editor itself? I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to insert tables in your content there are plugins for that.

Comment: Yes, layout of "edit page" like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/screenshot25550828at100.png/ that rearrange layout for editing or create new post.

Comment: That looks like a total rewrite, have you considered doing it on the frontend?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the image you posted, you have two sane options:

- Implement a frontend add/edit UI
- Hide the posts admin UI and build your own

Considering that eitherway a rewrite is needed, I recommend using the frontend.

If you really want, you could hide all the metaboxes etc on the edit page and add your own at the bottom, but, this is 95% of the work for the above, **in addition** to hiding all the rest and tracking changes across versions, and the eventual maintenance nightmare.

Refer to [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post), this will be the function you use to update the post in your save routine when the form is submitted

Comment: Now I was implemented custom-UI in "wp-admin" zone with original Wordpress layout for `wp-admin/edit.php`, `wp-admin/post.php` Everything is properly work ! even Javascript. but I want to modified layout for `edit-form-advance.php` as I was researched that contained "editing layout" for `edit.php` and `post.php`. as mentioned I didn't want to edit these file directly. but as you seen in captured image, I was editing layout in `edit-form-advance.php` directly as not found any solution for this currently. http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/3356/screenshot25550828at539.png